# python database table linking

Tags: python, web2py

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to make a simple bulletin board system app using web2py. I am trying to add a post into a certain board and I linked the post and board by including the following field in my post table: Field('board_id', db.board). When I try to create a post inside a particular board it gives me an error: "OperationalError: no such column: board.id". My code for create_posts:

```
    def add_post():
        board = db.board(request.args(0))
        form = SQLFORM(db.post)
        db.pst.board_id.default = db.board.id
        if form.process().accepted:
            session.flash = T('The data was inserted')
            redirect(URL('default', 'index'))
        return dict(form=form, board=board)
```

When I try to do {{=board}} on the page that shows the posts in a certain board, I get Row {'name': 'hi', 'id': 1L, 'pst': Set (pst.board_id = 1), 'description': 'hi'} so I know it's there in the database. But when I do the same thing for the "add post" form page, it says "board: None". I'm extremely confused, please point me in the right direction!

Comment: `db.board(request.args(0))` returns the record from `db.board` whose `id` is equal to `request.args(0))` or `None` if there is no record with that `id`. So, either there is no value for `request.args(0)`, or its value does not match any of your record IDs. Presumably you are generating links to `add_post` that include a record ID as the first URL arg. How are you generating those links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be several problems with your function. First, you are assigning the default value of the `board_id` field to be a `Field` object (i.e., `db.board.id`) rather than an actual id value (e.g., `board.id`). Second, any default values should be assigned *before* creating the `SQLFORM`.

Finally, you pass `db.post` to `SQLFORM`, but in the next line, the post table appears to be called `db.pst` -- presumably these are not two separate tables and one is just a typo.

Regarding the issue of `{{=board}}` displaying `None`, that indicates that `board = db.board(request.args(0))` is not retrieving a record, which would be due to `request.args(0)` itself being `None` or being a value that does not match any record id in `db.board`. You should check how you are generating the links that lead to `add_post` and confirm that there is a valid `db.board` id in the first URL arg. In any case, it might be a good idea to detect when there is no valid board record and either redirect or display an error message.

So, your function should look something like this:

```
def add_post():
    board = db.board(request.args(0)) or redirect(URL('default', 'index'))
    db.pst.board_id.default = board.id
    form = SQLFORM(db.pst)
    if form.process(next=URL('default', 'index'),
                    message_onsuccess=T('The data was inserted'))
    return dict(form=form, board=board)
```

Note, if your are confident that links to `add_post` will include valid board IDs, then you can eliminate the first line altogether, as there is no reason to retrieve a record based on its ID if the only field you need from it is the ID (which you already have). Instead, the second line could be:

```
    db.pst.board_id.default = request.args(0) or redirect(URL('default', 'index'))
```

Comment: thank you SO much!!!! this line worked when i replaced the first two lines with it:  db.pst.board_id.default = request.args(0) or redirect(URL('default', 'index'))